# Slicer Filtering in power bi api not working as expected C#

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, .net-5, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-api

I need to export a pbi report into pdf with slicer filters.

I have created an ExportReportRequest object and passed to `await Client.Reports.ExportToFileInGroupAsync(GroupId,ReportId, exportRequest);`

```
var exportRequest = new ExportReportRequest

                {
                    Format = Format.PDF,
                    PowerBIReportConfiguration = new PowerBIReportExportConfiguration(){
                        Pages = new List<ExportReportPage>()
                            {  new ExportReportPage(){
                                PageName = "_pageName_" ,
                            }},
                        ReportLevelFilters = "Key/Owner eq 'Pantheon'"
                    }
                };
```

I don't getting any errors or exceptions on further steps. What I getting is only the page without applied slicers. what i want is the page with applied slicers. (Table, Field and Values are valid). 
Did I miss anything to add ? please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Exported the Report to pdf in a React application with filters applied. Filters are applied to my exported report. Here is my JSON body passed during request

```
{
        format: 'PDF',
        powerBIReportConfiguration: {
            pages: [{pageName: 'ReportSection3'}],
            reportLevelFilters: [{
                filter: "Store/Territory eq 'NC'"
            }]
        }
    }
```

Not sure why filters are not applied if it's not throwing error. Recheck once. If not able to figure out, A workaround is to Apply the filters and capture it in a bookmark state and pass the bookmarkstate in [powerBIReportConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file#powerbireportexportconfiguration)